# Firebase reads/writes not working with security rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm struggling to understand security rules in firebase

I've been using the standard development rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

and my app reads/writes successfully. I have protected pages and then once a user signs in, I make various calls to pull the data. I call my lambda function from an api gateway endpoint and inside the lambda I have `let readData = firebaseApp.database().ref(users/${userID}/data)`
once inside there I do

```
readData.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const data = snapshot.val()
        const myData = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
            return data[key]
        })
        callback(null, {
            body: JSON.stringify(myData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            statusCode: 200,
        })
    } else {
        callback(null, {
            body: JSON.stringify([]),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            statusCode: 200,
        })
    }
})
```

the moment I update the security rules to be

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it completely fails and the lambda times out. I've gone to the rules and the simulator 
and gone to `/users/aisofnasfoi` (random id) and then turned on authentication, selected `google` as the provider and typed in the id. this works.

so I'm wondering what else I need to do in my code to send through this authenticated request?

added extra code:
so im parsing the user from localStorage if there, if not, im adding them there
this ensures I know they are logged in

```
 const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')))

useEffect(() => {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(user))
            setLoaded(true)
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
            setLoaded(true)
            console.log(user, 'USER NOT LOGGED IN')
        }
    })
```

further code :

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(user))
                console.log(user, 'user') // this console logs the user object and uid lives in there with the value of: `2BnDBSvIhwfoYWKIwGH20rUzyKv1`
```

that is then later passed to my function here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user.isLoggedIn) {
        fetchData(user.details.uid)
    }
}, [user.isLoggedIn])
```

this function is defined here: `export const fetchData = (id) => ({ type: 'GET_USER_DATA', id: id })`

and in turn an redux-observable is listening to it here which calls this endpoint. when the security rules are turned off it always gets the correct data for the correct logged in user. since turning them on to be stricter I'm getting timeouts:

`https://API_GATE_WAY_ENDPOINT/data?userId=${action.id}` (same id that came from the above)

Comment: Instead of describing how you ensure the user is signed in before calling this code, edit your question to show the actual code that does that. If the code to sign in is too complex to share, at least `console.log(userID)`, and include the updated code and its output in the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi thanks for the reply. sorry I'm just unclear on what extra code you want to see? my user logs in, (using onauthstatechanged) then I save that response to my redux store. then I make this request on mount of one of my components by calling my api gateway endpoint and then that triggers my lambda (which you can see above) and that is what speaks to firebase. is there something else I need to call to really make sure the user is validated?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added some more code in the meantime around the logging in

Comment: Again: instead of describing code, show a (preferably) single snippet that any of us can copy/paste to reproduce the problem, or ensure that all values that the code/rules depend on are logged, and both the logging code and output are in your question. Since your rules depends on `auth.uid`, you should log the UID in your code and show the code and output in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok I have added all that now under `Further Code`

Comment: where is firebase getting `auth.uid` from in here: `".read": "$uid === auth.uid",`

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#auth

Comment: yeh I've seen that. I'm just still not sure why this isn't working? `".read": "$uid === auth.uid",`

Comment: when clearly the `$uid` and the `auth.uid` do match

Comment: is it not possible to log them both out somewhere to see what firebase thinks they are?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen should I be looking for which uid? `user.uid` or `user.providerData[0].uid`?

Comment: sorry to keep posting but I really need to get this sorted. I can't see the `auth` variable anywhere in the users details? where should it be?

Comment: How do all the snippets of code relate? Are you sure the `onAuthStateChanged` has fired before you attach the listener to `readData.on('value', ...`?

Comment: yup 100%. I've just moved ` fetchData(user.uid)` inside the `onAuthStateChanged` handler so it only gets called if user exists and im passing in `user.uid`. so no way readData can get called before it because `fetchData` is what triggers the lambda. (and even then, im using the `user.uid` which is what is what im making the request with

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want straightforward answers, you have to ask a minimal  and complete question. The code is fragmented and confusing. No way to tell why it's not working from snippets.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you do not need to store the user id. Firebase SDKs do that for you. This is likely related to the bug and not necessary. Just call onAuthStateChanged() during initial load and see if the existing auth token is valid or if the client needs to auth. Use getCurrentUser() to grab the existing creds. Don't store it.

Comment: I appreciate the snippets aren't ideal but I was trying to give as much context as possible. as far as I can see I'm doing everything "by the docs". I've just checked getCurrentUser and it indeed gives me the correct user so I can't see why on earth the firebase rules wont let me write data. is there any way to see the I do `$uid === auth.id`  but `auth.id` is actually coming back as to help me debug? also I need to store the user uid so I can make posts to the `/user/uid` part of my database. thank you for you reply by the way, I appreciate it